# Having MVC 2 with both VS 2008 and VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I had VS 2010, which gave me MVC 2 out of the box. Then, I installed VS 2008 Professional Edition.

I wanted to do MVC 2 with VS 2008. I had to download MVC 2 for VS 2008 SP1, which I did. Now, when I try to install MVC 2 for VS 2008 SP1, it tells me that I already have MVC 2 installed in another location and I must remove that first. I guess it is referring to the MVC 2 installation that VS 2010 gave me.

How do I let both of them co-exist?

Answer (score 1):

Remove MVC which was installed with VS2010 (it's avaible in add/remove in control panel) and install [MVC 2 RTM](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9&displaylang=en). It's newer then MVC that you get with VS 2010 and it should work with both versions of VS.

Comment: Thanks. I did just that. It is now working with VS 2008 but I don't see the templates in the VS 2010 New Project dialog.